# Do I need to lock the dependent private method?

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

Say I have a public `method1` calling a private `method2`, I use a lock to ensure the thread safety of `method1`, do I need to use a lock on `method2`? `method2` is only being called through `method1`.

Comment: You should work on marking questions with question marks (`?`) and statements with full stops (`.`), otherwise your post is rather hard to digest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `method2` is called only by `method1`, then you don't have to use a lock in `method2`. The one lock in `method1` is enough.

When a thread class `method1`, it will acquire the lock, call `method2`, `method2` *won't be executing concurrently* by another thread since the other thread should have called `method1` first, and in such a case, `method1` would fail to acquire the lock.

Comment: Assuming synchronized methods, this is true. If the synchronization is performed on different objects then it might not be.